# How to use a downloaded Jekyll theme

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I downloaded a Jekyll theme called Clean Blog and put it into the same directory as my folder that I used to install Jekyll using `gem`

How do I use the theme on my Jekyll blog? I'm using it locally.

Comment: Are you using [this one](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-clean-blog-jekyll)?

Comment: Yes I am using that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [Clean Blog by Start Bootstrap - Jekyll Version](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-clean-blog-jekyll) you need to use [bundler](http://bundler.io/).

The gem files are specified in `/Gemfile`, move to the directory where you downloaded it and execute:

```
$ bundle install
```

Then you have jekyll with that theme.